# CMYK vs sRGB - which one is better

Tags: image-processing, cmyk, srgb

Guys i have 2 images one with CMYK color model and other with sRGB.. I would like to find out which color model is better to use while dealing with image processing like resizing, cropping, color filling etc.. 
 Thanks in advance guys.. !

Comment: for resizing, cropping and color filling it should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMYK color space is used for print, (s)RGB is used for screens (web, monitors, tvs etc). If one were to open a CMYK document in a viewer/program that doesn't support the color profile (which is not uncommon, since CMYK isn't as widely supported as RBG) the colors would appear to be extremely over-saturated. If you are altering the images for use on the web, or in an application, I would highly recommend that you use some variant of RGB.

In short, neither is really better than the other in general, it all depends on where you will be using the images (apples and oranges, comes to mind). CMYK is better for print, and (s)RGB is better for screens.

**UPDATE in response to OP's comment:**

Just to be clear (forgive me if you already know this) color space/profiles do not affect the resolution of an image, they only affect how the colors are handled/encoded. Resolution is only affected by file dimensions, DPI/PPI (dots/pixels per inch) and compression.

**UPDATE 2 in response to OP's comment:**

I'm not familiar with "Imagemagick", but in general, I can tell you that I've converted thousands of documents to RGB from CMYK (and vise versa) and never noticed any degradation in quality, when the file is viewed in a program that supports the color profile. The only exception is when converting to CMYK **FROM** RGB, it is possible to lose a wee bit of vibrancy (due to the fact that CMYK is a smaller color space. Like I said before, if by "quality" you mean "resolution" the color profile won't effect it, the image won't suddenly lose clarity, when switching color profiles. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: alright sir.. you think there will be any color/information/quality loss if we try to convert it to sRGB from CMYK using imagemagick as an image processing software ?

Comment: Please see my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "better" for these purposes. In general you should use the color space/model that best aligns with your output device, like CMYK for paper and sRGB for screen, but for manipulations (such as resize, crop) they are the same.

Comment: Sir they are 2 different color models and there are no differences in quality of image using these two ?? is it  assured?

Comment: Any quality difference will be explained by the quality of the image processing software: manipulations that force software to mix colors, like resize, may have a biased output if the software does not know the color model well. Manipulations that don't require mixing, like cropping, won't show any difference.

Comment: am using imagemagick, you have any idea there is any information/quality loss

Answer (score 0):

the best is sRGB because is larger and the color are better preserved. AdobeRGB is even better.  But remember that if you want to distribute you graphic image you have to know what kind of device will be used to print/view. You may use also a AdobeRGB but when you print it, you'll be sad, because many colors of AdobeRGB cannot be seen on a paper.

Cheers

Comment: alright sir.. you think there will be any color loss if we try to convert it to sRGB from CMYK using imagemagick as an image processing software ?